# How to render jade template and call that in a div using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, pug

I am trying to load a jade page using  the jQuery `.load` function.
I have a div in index page where i want to load the other jade template when an anchor is clicked.

Jquery code is mentioned below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.navsub').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var page = $(this).attr('href');
            var pageout = $.get(page);
            if (page=='#')
                return false;
            else
            alert("working");
            $('#content_contain').load(pageout);
        });
});
```

and now rendering the page in app.js, rendering code in app.js is mentioned below

```
app.get('/somepage', function (req, res) {
    var some = res.render('somepage', { title: 'someotherpage' });
    res.send(some);
});
```

Now the question is how do i render the jade template which will be called when anchor will be clicked and call it inside a div.

The jQuery code above works fine if the page extension is `.html` or `.php`, but not with `.jade`.

Can someone explain why this doesn't work?
I'm using node.js and express.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mentioning the route in index.js and restarting the application fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

[`res.render`](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L938) doesn't return anything, but takes a callback. So do this instead:

```
res.render('somepage', { title: 'someotherpage' }, function(err, some){
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.send(some);
});
```

Comment: it is not sending the page to ajax, so that ajax will display that page in `#content_contain`